# how to remove the apllication bar at the top of a android page?

Tags: android

how can i remove these application bar at the top of any android app which i create?
in the case that it is not possible, is it possible to change it? (i don't mean the text, i mean the layout and style)

[image: screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your problem, then it's very simple.

Just add this line, to your activity (in the manifest xml file) :

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

For example :

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity"

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this call on the onCreate method of the activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here what i did in order to have my application fullscreen without title:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The latest line is for keep the screen on during your program execution, and prevent the screen to be locked.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

That line remove the Title from your application.

And the FLAG_FULLSCREEN hide the statusbar from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

You just copy tihs code in onCreate and thi is it :D

Answer (score 0):

Or ... simply put this in you manifest file for each activity.
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove that from the whole application, write this in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```